# Possible to open a remote pdf file thru a native android app?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want to open a remote pdf file thru a native app installed on the android device. Is that possible ?
I tried using an intent with the mime type but that doesnt work. I do not want to use the docs.google.com ref.

Any suggestions ?

For ref. :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(<remote_path>));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (activities.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(<remote_pdf>), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Post some code for what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I needed to implement something like you say. My clients were not satisfied with the docs.google.com url, and the alternative I found was download the remote pdf to to the device (in public folder, like external storage), and start an intent with the local `Uri` of the pdf that has been downloaded. Otherwise, if the user had not installed any pdf reader, I launched the doc.google.com url with the url of the pdf, but this issue will be launched in some special cases.

PD: If you use this approach, make sure that you download the file in a public directory, or the pdf reader will not be able to open it.

Regards